# SQLite 3 in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

As of the symfony2 doc http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html symfony 2 requires that you have the Sqlite3  enabled . Where exactly is it used in symfony2 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure that Symfony's debug toolbar requires SQLite to work, I don't know if something else uses it.

Comment: That's it. It's used for debug toolbar.

Comment: Thanks for that answer . But I disabled sqlite3 extension from php.ini and tried to load my symfony application , but it worked , including the profiler  !

Comment: Are you sure of that? Have you restarted the web server after making changes to your php.ini? Because I did the same test and Symfony says: "You need to enable either the SQLite3 or PDO_SQLite extension for the profiler to run properly."

Comment: Also I am not sure, but I think in only applies to Symfony 2.0. I do get this error with 2.0 but not in 2.1. It might only be required on the profile for 2.0